# Slide Page Ids are undefined Google Slides API (res.data.slides.objectId)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-slides-api

I am trying to list all of the slide object id's in a given presentation. However, `res.data.slides.objectId` always come back as undefined. Code:

```
slides.presentations.get({
    presentationId: id,
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return error(err);
    length = res.data.slides.length;
    for (a = 0; a <= length; a++){
        let ids = res.data.slides.objectId[a];
        console.log(ids);
        slideObjectIds.push(ids);
        console.log(slideObjectIds);
    }
});
```

I've tried using `JSON.parse(res.data.slides.objectId)`, but this stops at *u*, it will probably be *undefined*. I know it is res.data.slides.objectId because I starting by logging (`console.log`)`res`, It was under `data`, then I logged `res.data`, and so forth, and found that `res.data.slides` worked, but `res.data.slides.objectId` did not work. 
[Here is the response page.](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations#Presentation)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, `res` is an object **NOT** an array, the way I was trying to reference this was by addressing the index. I was able to fix this by using this code:

```
res.data.slides.forEach((file) => {slideObjectIds.push(file.objectId)});
```

It pushes the object is to the array `slideObjectIds`.